# How to call NodeJS function (and get parameters) from javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have HTML, javascript and 2 NodeJS files. One node file is server and the other is filled with functions. So, how to call NodeJS function (and get parameters) from javascript file? Here's how they briefly look:

**index.js (server)**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express()
const db = require('./queries')
const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
)

app.use(
  cors({
    //Omogućen pristup sa svih adresa
    origin: "*"
  })
)

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.json({ info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API' })
})

app.get('/konzola', db.getKonzola)
app.get('/blagajna', db.getBlagajna)
app.get('/knzid/:p_knz_sif', db.getKnzId)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

**queries.js (other node file)**
One function example

```
...

const getKonzola = (request, response) => {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM konzola where knz_id in (1,2,3) ORDER BY knz_id', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
}

module.exports = {
  getKonzola
}
```

**javascript.js**

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET',`http://ip4_adress:3000/konzola`);
request.send();
request.onload = ()=> {
  console.log(request);
  if(request.status === 200){
    console.log(JSON.parse(request.response));
  } else {
    console.log(request);
    console.log(`error ${request.status}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is happening when the `XMLHttpRequest` is executed? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I fixed the error, but yes, I was getting an error. Still thanks for reply!

Comment: You should create an answer for how you solved it to possibly help others facing the same issue.